# bipartite graph creation using sparseMatrix

Tags: r, igraph

I am creating a bipartite graph and computing for the maximal matching as shown below.

```
adjspars <- sparseMatrix(i=adj.mat[,1], j=adj.mat[,2], x=1, 
    dims=c(npri,ncon), dimnames=list(paste0("p",1:npri),paste0("c",1:ncon)))
igrph <- graph.incidence(adjspars)
igrph.match <- maximum.bipartite.matching(igrph)
```

The output of `print(igrph)` is

```
IGRAPH UN-B 67368 3344133 --
+ attr: type (v/l), name (v/c)
```

For the above graph the amount of time taken is as follows

```
create sparse matrix   .51s
create graph         50.66s
bipartite matching     .16s
```

Is there a different way of performing the create graph step which would be faster?

Comment: Yes, there is a faster way.

Comment: @GaborCsardi I did find another method which uses `graph.bipartite`.  It works an order of magnitude faster.  Is that the "faster way" that you were referring to?